# How to install numpy in a user specified directory using conda command prompt

Tags: python, numpy, conda, numpy-ndarray

I am using numpy in a Package but since it was backdated I unistalled it and now trying to reinstall it in a specified path. But after installing it several times I can not figure out how to install it to the specified path since it only installed inside the miniconda3 directory but I need it in another directory

```
(base) C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (1.18.1)
```

I wanted to install it in `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages` but it was installed in `c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages`

Comment: Your main python is the anaconda one so the lib will be installed in the conda path.

Comment: No I am using mainly IDLE from python and using anaconda command prompt for installation only

Comment: Pip belongs to a python install. The version of pip has to do with your PATH variable, not your current directory.

Comment: Don't use your base Conda environment! Create a separate environment for each one of your projects. Why do you need NumPy to be installed in a certain directory in the first place? What is the point of having multiple Python installations alongside Conda/Anaconda? I would strongly recommend reading the Conda and Anaconda documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case when you have multiple python installed, select the path of the python.exe what you want to use along with the package. Then in the command prompt you have to install the package by the command

```
<PATH\python.exe> -m pip install numpy
```

This will work if you have pip installed previously.

Comment: I think this is quite misleading advice.

Comment: @AMC ok u are ri8. but for some packages conda is not working and i have to use the alternate way. But can we use conda also to install a package to a path specified other than miniconda3-path